# how to create an Angular circular progress bar using SVG

Tags: css, angular, svg

I have created a design for angular circular progress bar. The issue is that i want to give the percentage value dynamic . I have got the dynamic value from API but i have no idea how should i implement it to create a circular progress bar using SVG. I'll share my html skeleton and the css i use.

```css
.track,
    .filled {
      stroke-width: 10;
      fill: none;
    }
    
    .track {
      stroke: rgba(160, 215, 231, 0.85);
    }
    
    .filled {
      stroke: blue;
      stroke-dashoffset: 202;
      stroke-dasharray: 440;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="iconbox-singleD7 dashboard-height">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-35 0 190 190" class="mw">
                <circle class="track" cx="60" cy="60" r="55" />
                <text x="40" y="60" fill="#fff">Patients</text>
                <text x="50" y="75" fill="#fff">{{totalPatient}}</text>
                <circle class="filled" cx="60" cy="60" r="55" />
                <circle cx="30" cy="136" r="5" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3" fill="blue" /><text x="40" y="140" fill="#fff">Male {{malePercentage}}%</text>
                <circle cx="30" cy="152" r="5" stroke="rgba(160, 215, 231, 0.85)" stroke-width="3" fill="rgba(160, 215, 231, 0.85)" /><text x="40" y="155" fill="#fff">Female {{femalePercentage}}%</text>
              </svg>
            </div>
           </div>
```

What i want is that. Lets say i get a male percentage = 70% or any value from an API i want to set the progress bar according to the percentage i get from API. How can i achieve that .i'm not familier with SVG. So any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The total length of the circle's stroke is 345.57519189487726 calculated like 2*PI*radius. This is 100%. For 70% you multiply it with 0.7. In SVG there isalso a `pathLength` attribute.   You can set the length of the path to 100. In this case 70% is 70. Use it for the stroke-dasharry value.  `stroke-dasharry="70 30"`

Comment: can i get a working example. I'm just using 70% as an example i can get any value from an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello here is the code pen: https://codepen.io/Echyzen/pen/LYBraGB

```
var percentage = 75;
var a = -3.46;
var b = 440;
function changePer() {
   const finalOffset = Math.round(a*percentage+b)
   const concernedCircle = document.getElementsByClassName('filled')[0];
  concernedCircle.style.strokeDashoffset = finalOffset;
}
```

which extract the a and b of the affine function.
You have to click on the button to execute the 75% percentage.

Or using querySelector:

```
var percentage = 70;
var a = -3.46;
var b = 440;
function changePer() {
   const finalOffset = Math.round(a*percentage+b)
   const concernedCircle = document.querySelector('.filled');
   concernedCircle.style.strokeDashoffset = finalOffset;
}
```

Comment: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element' facing this issue.

Comment: That's means you change your svg again check if you have the class="filled" in your HTML.
Because as you can see with your example furnished it works on the codepen.

Try with the other example I edit the message.

Comment: thanks i did slight changes and it work. i added toString(); in finalOffset and worked.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the `<progress-circle>` native Web Component I built : https://pie-meister.github.io/

It is unlicensed Open [Source code](https://github.com/pie-meister/pie-meister.github.io/blob/main/PieMeister-with-Progress.js); do with it whatever your want. Documentation at [Dev.to](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/what-web-technologies-are-required-to-draw-a-pie-chart-in-2021-spoiler-alert-a-standard-web-component-will-do-1j56)

[image]

```html
<progress-circle value="100%">Web Components</progress-circle>
<progress-circle value="71%" stroke="red">React</progress-circle>
<progress-circle value="90%" stroke="orange">Others</progress-circle>

<script src="https://pie-meister.github.io/PieMeister-with-Progress.min.js"></script>

<style>
  progress-circle {
    font-family: Arial;
    width: 180px; /* StackOverflow viewport */
  }
  progress-circle::part(label) {
    font-size:70px;
  }
</style>
```